# How can I abstract three objects of the same type coming from three different services?

Tags: c#, abstraction, service-reference

I am using a service with several endpoints divided out by their subsystem.  All the systems have a set of standard objects that are used to pass structured data back and forth.  In a given application, I am using three of the seven available end points. `ServiceA`, `ServiceB` and `ServiceC`. Establishing a connect to each returns a structure of `EnvironmentVariableType`, but because each comes back from a different service, C# considers them to be different types.  `ServiceA.EnvironmentVariableType`, `ServiceB.EnvironmentVariableType` and `ServiceC.EnvironmentVariableType`.

Is there a way to abstract them and treat all three as the same object type?

Comment: Can you create an `interface` that is shared by the three (seven)?

Comment: Do the endpoints have all the same types, or just some common types? In the former case, you can reference only one endpoint in your project, and create several instances of the client class by passing the appropriate URLs (I haven't used service references in a long time, but I'm pretty sure it's possible)

Comment: CommuSoft - I have no control over the remote system, so I do not believe that there is a way for me to create a common interface

Comment: Thomas - I am not sure of the distinction between same types and common types.  The services all have a struct of EnvironmentVariableType, and they are each the same in every way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create adapter layer via interface.
  Derive your own classes from this interface and each class access one service  which convert service objects or types to your application local types.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the generated code for the services to insert a common interface or to use the same types you could instead use [Impromptu Interface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface) which would allow you to take the result of each call and make it `ActLike` an interface you define. It's available in Nuget.